# Count whatcounts the number of pure-integers in the string

Tags: python

Consider this C Program, C++ Program, Java Program, C# Program, or Python Program. It reads one string from the file input.txt and and does some processing on the string by calling process on it, which returns an int. This int is printed the output file output.txt.

Currently, process does not do anything. It just returns 0. You have to change this program so that it counts the number of pure-integers in the string. For the purposes of this program, assume that a pure-integer is any sequence of 1 or more consecutive digits (i.e. 0 to 9). Ignore + and - signs, decimal points and other complicated numbers. Thus, if the input string is:

“I will eat 2 burgers 23 fries & 1.25 cokes l8r”
The output should be:

5
(Because, 1.25 is treated as two different numbers 1 and 25, and 8 is also treated as a number.)

Comment: You need to ask an actual question, you have just provided us your idea with no way of us knowing what you have tried, if at all..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.